# How to keep only values in one column that match the other column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

Here is my df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lifetime = c(
    "tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,cocaine,stim",
    "tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,cocaine,stim,inhal",
    "tobacco,alcohol,stim,rx",
    "tobacco,alcohol,cocaine,stim",
    "tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,opioids,cocaine,stim,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal",
    "tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,stim"
  ),
  remission = c(
    "rx",
    "cannabis,opioids,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal",
    "tobacco,cannabis,opioids,cocaine,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal",
    "cannabis,opioids,cocaine,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal",
    "alcohol,cocaine,stim,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal",
    "cannabis,opioids,cocaine,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal"
  )
)
```

I want to match the two columns and

> if a substance is present lifetime, should be kept in remission column
> if a substance is present in lifetime, it should be dropped in remission column
> if nothing matches, the column remission should return empty.

I can get if its a complete match to work, but can't find anything about partial matches and then keeping and dropping values

Comment: What does your expected result look like?

Comment: Exactly like what TarJae posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way how we could do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(lifetime, sep = ",") %>% 
  separate_rows(remission, sep= ",") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(remission = case_when(
    str_detect(lifetime, paste(remission, collapse = "|")) ~ lifetime
  )) %>% 
  distinct(remission, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(remission) | max(row_number()) == 1) %>% 
  summarise(remission = toString(remission)) %>% 
  right_join(df %>% 
               mutate(id = row_number()), by = "id") %>% 
  select(lifetime, remission = remission.x)
```

```
  lifetime                                                                   remission                                               
  <chr>                                                                      <chr>                                                   
1 tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,cocaine,stim                                      NA                                                      
2 tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,cocaine,stim,inhal                                cannabis, inhal                                         
3 tobacco,alcohol,stim,rx                                                    tobacco                                                 
4 tobacco,alcohol,cocaine,stim                                               cocaine                                                 
5 tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,opioids,cocaine,stim,rx,halluc,dissoc,tranq,inhal alcohol, cocaine, stim, rx, halluc, dissoc, tranq, inhal
6 tobacco,alcohol,cannabis,stim                                              cannabis
```